# Don't replace existing urls regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Below code works well, its able to replace any tag it find with a link, but tags with existing links are also replaced, like @google which should be ignored.

```
<div class="post">
    <p class="test">First text some @microsoft</p>
    <p class="test">Second text with <a href="http://www.google.com">@google</a>, @yahoo</p> 
    <p class="test">Third text with @apple, @stackoverflow</p>
</div>  


$('.post p.test').each(function (i, el) {
    $(el).html($(el).html().replace(/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim, function (match, username) {
        return '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + username + '">' + match + '</a>';
    }));
});
```

I have had no luck with regex, I want jquery to ignore tags with existing link: http://jsfiddle.net/ereXZ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a negative lookahead `(?!</a>)` after your link regex, see [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ereXZ/2/)

Note that the `[\w\-]+` has been changed to `[\w\-]+\b(?!</a>)`. The `\b` makes sure the regex matches up to the end of the tag, and the `(?!</a>)` makes sure tags followed by a closing link tag are not matched (and the `/` needs to be delimited).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `html` of your element, maybe you could iterate over its contents using [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), filter them to only consider text nodes (or to exclude `a` nodes), and replace that.

This is as far as I got, <strike>unfortunatly I don't know yet how to replace a text node for something else</strike> (*Edit*: it's working now):

```
$(el)
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    })
    .each(function() {
        var span = $(this).wrap('<span/>').parent();
        span.html(span.html().replace(/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim, function (match, username) {
            return '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + username + '">' + match + '</a>';
        }));
    });
```

It wraps the text node inside a `span` before replacing its contents, since you can't add other elements inside a text node.

Live example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/BEMDX/)